# Where does the "/dev/zero (deleted)", "anon_inode:dmabuf" comes from in /proc/$PID/maps?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, maps, pid, proc

I am debugging a embedded Linux memory exhaustion problem and notice that are a lot of /dev/zero(deleted) and anon_inode:dmabuf entries pop in and out of the /proc/$PID/maps file of the running process.

I tried use "strace -f -e trace=mmaps2,munmap,open,mremap " to track the syscall.  But I don't see any mmap/munmap/open()  activities when the those /dev/zero entries are pop in/out of the /proc/$PID/maps file.

Does anyone know where those entries might be coming from?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

It is related to the egl driver inside the embedded SOC.    The egl driver did the mmap inside the kernel space.  Therefore the strace on the user space can't track down the kernel mmap (equivalent) api calls.